# Mock classes on unit tests with Codeception and Laravel 5 module

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-5, mocking, codeception

In unit tests, this doesn't work:

```
class SomeClassCest
{
    public function tryToTest(UnitTester $I)
    {
        $mock = Mockery::mock(MyClass::class);
        $mock->shouldReceive('action')->once()->andReturn(true);
        $I->haveInstance(MyClass::class, $mock);

        $classToTest = app(SomeClass::class);
        // this method calls the MyClass action method
        $classToTest->run();

        // some asserts here
    }
}
```

The mock doesn't take effect, the `$mock->action` is never called, the real implementation is called instead. How to mock classes on unit tests with Codeception and the Laravel 5 module?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in unit tests, the methods `amOnRoute`, `amOnPage` are not called, so the `Laravel5->doRequest()` will not apply bindings, so, in order to mock a class, in the Unit helper from Codeception suite:

```
class Unit extends \Codeception\Module
{

    /**
     * @param $realClass
     * @param $mock
     */
    public function mockClass($realClass, $mock)
    {
        $this->getModule('Laravel5')->getApplication()->instance($realClass, $mock);
    }

}
```

In the unit test:

```
class SomeClassCest
{
    public function tryToTest(UnitTester $I)
    {
        $mock = Mockery::mock(MyClass::class);
        $mock->shouldReceive('action')->once()->andReturn(true);
        $I->mockClass(MyClass::class, $mock);

        $classToTest = app(SomeClass::class);
        // this method calls the MyClass action method
        $classToTest->run();

        // the mocked classs is used insetad of the real one

        // do some asserts here
    }
}
```